# How to Authenticate .NET MVC on iFrame

Tags: iframe, .net-core, forms-authentication, abp, cookie-authentication

I am not experienced in .NET authentication, and haven't found a specific answer for this need.

I am developing a .NET Core 2.1 MVC app which will have to run on an iframe on a different .NET Framework 4.5.1 app, which uses a FormsAuthenticationTicket when authenticating users. I have access to the main app's code, but cannot change it.

The present requirement is to automatically authenticate the iframe app, which I am developing, automatically from the main app's cookie information. On my app the login uses ASP.NET boilerplate (Abp) users and login, and the database contains the same usernames that will be using from the main app's database (different databases, same username field).

I currently haven't been able to decrypt the cookie or find a way to configure the iframe app to support this, and would appreciate if someone would kindly steer me in the right direction.